# How to set $env:NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS to "default" value?

Tags: node.js, certificate

While trying to solve a Node certificates issue on my local, I had to set `$env:NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="D:\Source\project\fe\client.certificate.cer"`

If I remove the above "client.certificate.cer" from the disk, each time I run an npm command, npm looks for the above certificate "D:\Source\project\fe\client.certificate.cer" and gives me a warning that it's no longer the disk.

> Warning: ignoring extra certs from
> 'D:\Source\project\fe\client.certificate.cer', load failed:
> error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory.
>
> npm WARN config global '--global', '--local' are deprecated. Use '--location=global' instead.
>
> Warning: ignoring extra certs from 'D:\Source\project\fe\client.certificate.cer', load failed:
> error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory.

In order to set up the value of the $env:NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS= to a "default" one I run `$env:NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\mkcert\rootCA.pem`.
It works for the current instance of PowerShell, but if I run another one or I restart the PC, it returns to "D:\Source\project\fe\client.certificate.cer"

How can I update the value of $env:NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS permanently?

Comment: Have you tried modifying your system environment variables?

Comment: No... it seems that was the solution. Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the value of $env:NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS permanently, you will need to modify your system environment variables.

Comment: Use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS", "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\mkcert\rootCA.pem",  EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);`

to set it usinbg PowerShell.